# prevent div from overlapping other divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've looked through a dozen other similar questions as this one, but I don't think any of them are similar enough to my scenario. This isn't my exact setup, but I've simplified it to hopefully make it easier to explain and also answer.

I have 3 divs. If the window is wider than 600px, div1 and div2 should flow normally, floated left, and div3 should float to the right. Using a @media query, if the window is narrower than 600px, div 3 should appear above div1 and div2, pushing them down so they're stacked on top of each other.

I've tried experiementing with display and position properties on all 3 divs, and I can't figure out how to make this work. I'm working with a templated system, so I can't add a container. I can only work with these 3 divs.

```css
#id1 {
background: red;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}

#id2 {
background: yellow;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}

#id3 {
background: blue;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
float: right;
position: fixed;
top: 50px;
right: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 #id3 {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  }
 }
```

```html
<div id="id1">DIV 1</div>
<div id="id2">DIV 2</div>
<div id="id3">DIV 3</div>
```

Comment: Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/8xLfkg0d/ ? if you can change the html

Answer (score 1):

Set `position: relative` and correct `top`/`left`/`right` values:

```css
#id1 {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#id2 {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#id3 {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  right: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #id3 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: unset;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="id1">DIV 1</div>
<div id="id2">DIV 2</div>
<div id="id3">DIV 3</div>
```

To stack the `div#id3` on top, you'll need to use `position: absolute` and set custom top position for all 3 divs:

```css
#id1 {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#id2 {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#id3 {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  right: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #id1,
  #id2,
  #id3 {
    position: absolute;  
    top: 10px;
    float: none;    
  }
  #id1{ top: 110px; }
  #id2{ top: 210px; }
  #id3{ right: unset; }
}
```

```html
<div id="id1">DIV 1</div>
<div id="id2">DIV 2</div>
<div id="id3">DIV 3</div>
```

Comment: I need div3 to be first, at the top of the page. This makes it appear below div2.

Comment: @Robby Well in that case you'll need to set values manually, see edit

Comment: @ZohirSalak Its in the second snippet, surely you observed that there are 2 snippets in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order.
I hope this helps. If you need me to explain it to you, please let me know. I will be glad to.

```css
body {
    display: flex; 
    /* Optional, if you want the DIVs 100% width: */ 
    flex-direction: column;
}

#id1 {
background: red;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;

}

#id2 {
background: yellow;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;

}

#id3 {
background: blue;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
float: right;
position: fixed;
top: 50px;
right: 20px;

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    
    body > #id3 { order: 1; }
    body > #id1 { order: 2; }
    body > #id2 { order: 3; }
   
    
    #id3 {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
  }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="id1">DIV 1</div>
    <div id="id2">DIV 2</div>
    <div id="id3">DIV 3</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the best solution according to me

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with a perfect solution for my needs. Adding a `margin-top` to div1 in the @media query will bump it and div2 down:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 #id3 {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  }
    #id1 {
    margin-top: 100px;
    }
 }
```